# Fail to build opencv

Tags: java, android, c++, c, opencv

I am just learning android-opencv, and when I use Cartoonifier_Android. This error occurred and I don't know how to solve it

```
$ $NDK/ndk-build Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:opencv_contrib:
LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file Android NDK: Check that
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/user/share/OpenCV/../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_contrib.a
exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9b/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: ***
Android NDK: Aborting    。 stop。
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly show `libopencv_contrib.a` file is missing.
NDK looking at `/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/user/libs/armeabi-v7a/` location, But file not found. 
  You can do is either include above path in library search path for example: LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Linux or %PATH% in windows. OR you can copy  `libopencv_contrib.a` file to that location.
  My suggestion would be include library path.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have solved this problem,but the new problem has occure    [armeabi-v7a] Cygwin         : Generating dependency file converter script
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: cartoonifier <= jni_part.cpp
jni/jni_part.cpp:13:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9b/build/core/build-binary.mk:386: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cartoonifier/jni_part.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cartoonifier/jni_part.o] Error 1
i do not know how to solve it.

Comment: And the file opencv2/core/core.hpp i have found in my system

Comment: i use Cygwin64 to control it,the compiler maybe is gcc

Comment: then add `-IPATH/TO/core.hpp` switch to gcc command for example: i have it at: /cygdrive/c/opencv2/core/core.hpp then command would look like `gcc -I/cygdrive/c/opencv2/core cppfile.cpp`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion,but i follow your step and failed too.the compiler show  niuwei@WIN-CCD3447UA79 /cygdrive/c/OPENCV
$ gcc -I/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/user/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp
gcc: fatal error: no input file
compile stop。